# Displaying Combo Boxes with Items Outside SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a combo box(cboTest) that displays data from a connected SQL server using this code:

```
cboTest.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cboTest.ValueMember = "student_id";
cboTest.DisplayMember = "fullname";
cboTest.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

I want to add another item to this list, but from outside of what populates when the database is queried.  I thought the best way to do this would be `cboTest.Items.Add("Text");`  But that throws an error: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.  I would like the item to be on top of the combo box.  Kinda like this:

```
Text
DatabaseEntry1
DatabaseEntry2
...
```

Is there anyway I can add items without having to through dummy entries into my database?

Comment: Best way is to add to the ds.Tables.  You would need to add Columns/Rows.  Adding rows to data will allow you to use the ds.AcceptChanges which will save data in the database.

Comment: Which type is ds?

Comment: ds is a dataSet

Comment: @jdweng how do I add a new row to ds.Tables?

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Add.Row(new object[] { column array });